# How to Bind with Combobox in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I want to bind my collection of countries to a Combobox.

My XAML page looks as follows:

```
<pmControls:pmComboBox 
    Margin="3" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Countries}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Title,Mode=TwoWay}" >
</pmControls:pmComboBox>
```

I want to display Title as DataTextField.

Currently it shows namespace of country class in my combobox list .
I have also tried to add DisplayMemberPath but it also not works.

How can I setup the display field of Combobox to use a Binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do

```
DisplayMemberPath="Title"
SelectedValuePath="Title"
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Country,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: yes it works,i have tried it before but i was giving selectedValuePath="{Binding Title}".I didnt get the Differrece can you please explain.

Comment: you didn't specify `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Country,Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @Gayatri when the property you're setting is a 'path', you provide a property name (ie a string), not a binding.